# Ati Driver overturned my desktop :/

Tags: 13.04

I'm Turkish however my english not so good :D
Ok , I was installed Ati Radeon Mobility Xpress Driver , After that I restarted . After enter password , screen get dark and I seed background image and desktop elements but I couldn't  see menu on left and top menu :/ here so you understand you're going good :) Do you can help me

Thanks 
LlS|DarkBOY

Comment: You are experiencing the wrong screen resolution, that is why you are only seeing part of your desktop. To change the resolution do this.

You can use the command in your terminal xrandr -q to see what resolutions are available for your display

Xrandr is used to set the size, orientation and/or reflection of the outputs for a screen. It can also set the screen size.

To change the screen resolution to 1024 by 768 for instance, you would type: xrandr -s 1024x768

Just use that to change it to the size you want.

Comment: thanx but i found how i can do :D 'Install Ubuntu Again' ;)